# Where does a .paginate(...) call belong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

right now I have this in my controller:

```
def index
  @votes = Vote.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order=>"created_at DESC")
end
```

but I'm considering moving the .paginate to the views/index.html.erb (or a partial in that directory).  Paginate seems to me like it belongs in the View, as it manages how the Vote collection will be displayed.  Am I understanding the MVC separation correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you want it in the controller

`#paginate` alters your query so that it has a limit and a starting point.

So if you have 100 records, your paginate with page 2 will call something liks

```
select * from votes LIMIT(30) OFFSET(30)
```

And it will only return 30 records. If you did the same in the view, your @votes would have 1000 records and chop off what's needed.

Your view should be decently dumb and iterate over the records that the Controller gives it (which it gets from the model).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  I'm still pretty new to coding with the MVC framework so your description of the view will help me make future structuring decisions

Comment: One follow up question.  I have the following code in a view: `<%= render :partial => '/posts/display_posts',
  :locals => {:@posts => @category.posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :order=>'rank DESC')} %>` since this is a call from a view to another view, there's no other place that the paginate call can go, right?

Comment: "And it will only return 30 records. If you did the same in the view, your @votes would have 1000 records and chop off what's needed." <-- this is wrong. Rails lazily evaluates ActiveRecord queries. Unless he iterated over the collection before calling paginate, he wouldn't be pulling in all records in the database.

Comment: @ALW -- He would most certainly be executing a 'select * from' if he was then able to do a count, and then chop, you are technically correct.

Comment: @Eric -- in your example, in the controller I would have "@posts = @category.posts.paginate" and then in your partial do @posts.each

Comment: @Jesse: that's what I have in my posts_controller.  However, my follow up question code is from `views/categories/show.html.erb`.  I have an activeRecord association with (categories) `has_many :posts`.  I'd like to be able to list all posts in a category.  At the moment, that's done by passing category.posts into the partial.  I can't set category.posts to be category.posts.paginate in the category controller, can I?

Comment: @Jesse: Putting `@category.posts = @category.posts.paginate(...)` is indeed valid syntax.  However, when I make that assignment, `@category.posts.class` returns "Array".  It seems like I can't overwrite this association.  Additionally, the server takes a long time to evaluate that statement, so it seems like it's fetching the entirety of @category.posts.  Is there some special syntax I'm not aware of?

Comment: @posts = @category.posts.paginate(...)

Comment: that worked, thanks!  One issue I have with this is that  categories_controller has to be aware that `views/categories/show.html.erb` is calling on the `posts/_display_posts` partial.  A change in the view logic would require a change in the controller logic as well.  However, I can still see this as being the lesser of 2 evils.